# want each call to save to commit

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I have each call to save commit to the database?

I don't want to, at each interation of a loop that I am in, to call commit and then restart the transaction.

for my application, just having a commit at each session.save is fine.

Comment: @duffymo, and I REALLY do appreciate your help.  I am a newbie in Java and coding my first 'main' application and your help has been superb! (and everyone else ofcourse)

Comment: Mrblah, I have to admit to a little concern too -- 21 questions in the last 24 hours?  It feels like rather than spending any time trying to learn on your own, you're just getting to the point where most would start looking for a solution and posting here instead.  While that's not awful, it really is the one of the worst ways to learn a new language...

Comment: And I'd also point out that adding more detail to your questions would be very welcomed -- people shouldn't have to figure out what frameworks or libraries you're talking about solely from your tags.  Give people the info, up front, that they need to help you and it shows a great deal of respect for their time and effort...

Comment: delfuego, thanks for the advice, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: use a hibernate transaction:

```
Session s = factory.getCurrentSession();
try {
  s.beginTransaction();
  Thing thing = new Thing();
  s.save(thing);
  s.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  s.getTransaction().rollback();
  throw e;
}
```

Transaction handling with hibernate is detailed here:

- Sessions and Transactions - https://www.hibernate.org/42.html

In a servlet environment, hibernate recommends implementing a filter that starts a transaction when the request begins and ends it when the request is done. Sample code here:

- Open Session in View - https://www.hibernate.org/43.html

If using JTA or EJB there are methods to work with the existing transaction context as described in the guide.

You could alternatively turn autoCommit mode on (which is disabled by default). Each statement would effectively be executed in a separate transaction. This is controlled by the "hibernate.connection.autocommit" option. More details here:

- Non-Transactional Data Access and the Auto-Commit Mode - https://www.hibernate.org/403.html

Comment: No indication that he's using Hibernate at all.  It might be more complex than he can handle.

Comment: its hibernate, yeah that is why I tagged it as such :)

Comment: Be careful with that catch-clause there, you will loose the execption in case rollback() fails also. A workaround would be log the exception before attempting to rollback.

Comment: if rollback fails, it will throw an exception which gets propagated up the chain. you could use a chained exception if you need more detail

Answer (score 2):

So code it that way:

```
// connection is passed into the method.
try
{
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(...);
    // bind variables
    for (Collection stuff : stuffList)
    {  
        // save repeatedly 
    }
    connection.commit();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
   DatabaseUtils.rollback(connection);
}
finally
{
    DatbaseUtils.close(statement);
    DatabaseUtils.close(connection);
}
```

Transactions are a cross-cutting concern.  Best not to have transactional logic like this inside your persistence tier, especially if more than one data access object has to participate in a single unit of work.